# SQL count occurrences of values grouped by external tables references

Tags: sql, sql-server, self-join

What is the best approach in terms of performance and maintainability to count the number of occurrences of the same value in a table, grouping the results with the same reference that groups the entries of the table?

Let's say I have three tables (concepts have been shrinked in order to represent a scenario that is similar to the one I'm working on):

```
|----------|   |----------------|   |-----------------------------------|
|   MEAL   |   |      RECIPE    |   |          INGREDIENT_ENTRY         |
|----------|   |----------------|   |-----------------------------------|
| ID | ... |   | ID | ID_m | ...|   | ID | ID_r | amount and description|
|----------|   |----------------|   |-----------------------------------|
|  1 | ... |   |  1 |    1 | ...|   |  1 |    1 |       '15gr of yeast' |
|  2 | ... |   |  2 |    2 | ...|   |  2 |    4 |              '2 eggs' |
|  3 | ... |   |  3 |    3 | ...|   |  3 |    1 |      '300cl of water' |
|  4 | ... |   |  4 |    4 | ...|   |  4 |    2 |       '300cl of beer' |
|----------|   |  5 |    1 | ...|   |  5 |    3 |       '250cl of milk' |
               |  6 |    4 | ...|   |  6 |    5 |   '100gr of biscuits' |
               |  7 |    5 | ...|   |  7 |    2 |       '15gr of yeast' |
               |  8 |    6 | ...|   |  8 |    1 |      '500gr of flour' |
               |----------------|   |  9 |    2 |      '500gr of flour' |
                                    | 10 |    2 |        '10gr of salt' |
                                    | 11 |    4 |       '15gr of yeast' |
                                    |-----------------------------------|
```

The same MEAL can be cooked with a different RECIPE, and each RECIPE is made of different INGREDIENT_ENTRYs, organized in the same RECIPE by sharing the same ID_r value.

INGREDIENT_ENTRY.[amount and description] is a column of type VARCHAR(MAX), this is the value that must be compared.

In the example, making the query with (MEAL 1,RECIPE 1):

It has 3 ingredients (1,3,8), and shares:

- Two ingredients with RECIPE 2 (7,9) -> and so can be found in MEAL 2
- One ingredient with RECIPE 4 (11) -> and so can be found in MEAL 3

Result should look something like:

```
|------|   |--------|   |-------|
| MEAL |   | RECIPE |   | COUNT |
|------|   |--------|   |-------|
|    2 |   |      2 |   |     2 |
|    4 |   |      4 |   |     1 |
|------|   |--------|   |-------|
```

I'm experimenting with views to reduce SQL complexity, but I cannot make it with a single SQL statement and I would like to avoid going back and forth to code (C#) and perform multiple queries (for example query for every ingredient, and reconcile results with HashMaps or similar).

Please, note that I cannot modify the DB structure.

Comment: I would separate ingredients to its own table so each ingredients are unique. Also, I'd use table valued function to return the results.

Comment: @jae555 I cannot make changes to the structure of the DB, I will edit the question to clarify that, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find common ingredients using `EXISTS`. In the below I have simply used a Common table expression so that I don't have to write out the joins more than once to get back to a meal ID:

```
DECLARE @SelectedMealID INT = 1;

WITH LinkedData AS
(
    SELECT  MealID = r.ID_m,
            RecipeID = r.ID,
            Ingredient = i.[amount and description]
    FROM    RECIPE AS r
            INNER JOIN INGREDIENT_ENTRY AS i
                ON i.ID_r = r.ID
)
SELECT  a.MealID,
        a.RecipeID,
        CommonIngedients = COUNT(*)
FROM    LinkedData AS a
WHERE   a.MealID != @SelectedMealID
AND     EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    LinkedData AS b
            WHERE   b.Ingredient = a.Ingredient
            AND     b.MealID = @SelectedMealID
        )
GROUP BY a.MealID, a.RecipeID;
```

I have tested this with the below sample:

```
-- GENERATE TABLES AND DATA
DECLARE @Meal TABLE (ID INT);
INSERT @Meal (ID) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4);

DECLARE @Recipe TABLE (ID INT, ID_m INT);
INSERT @Recipe (ID, ID_m) 
VALUES (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 1), (6, 4), (7, 5), (8, 6);

DECLARE @Ingredient TABLE (ID INT, ID_r INT, AmountAndDescription VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT @Ingredient (ID, ID_R, AmountAndDescription)
VALUES
    (1, 1, '15gr of yeast'), (2, 4, '2 eggs'),
    (3, 1, '300cl of water'), (4, 2, '300cl of beer'),
    (5, 3, '250cl of milk'), (6, 5, '100gr of biscuits'),
    (7, 2, '15gr of yeast'), (8, 1, '500gr of flour'),
    (9, 2, '500gr of flour'), (10, 2, '10gr of salt'),
    (11, 4, '15gr of yeast');


-- TEST QUERY
DECLARE @SelectedMealID INT = 1;

WITH LinkedData AS
(
    SELECT  MealID = r.ID_m,
            RecipeID = r.ID,
            Ingredient = i.AmountAndDescription
    FROM    @Recipe AS r
            INNER JOIN @Ingredient AS i
                ON i.ID_r = r.ID
)
SELECT  a.MealID,
        a.RecipeID,
        CommonIngedients = COUNT(*)
FROM    LinkedData AS a
WHERE   a.MealID != @SelectedMealID 
AND     EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    LinkedData AS b
            WHERE   b.Ingredient = a.Ingredient
            AND     b.MealID = @SelectedMealID 
        )
GROUP BY a.MealID, a.RecipeID;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
MealID  RecipeID    CommonIngedients
------------------------------------------
2       2           2
4       4           1
```

*N.B. The expected output in the question differs slighly but I think the question may contain a typo (states Recipe 4 relates to meal 3, but this doesn't appear to be the case in the sample data)*

Comment: yes, there was a typo, sorry... In the effort of transposing my scenario to this simplified structure I missed this one, Thank you. Let me adapt your solution to my environment to see if it can fit...

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.